# string.Format in Data Annotation Validation Attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

Is there any way to set Data Annotation messages using formatted string instead of direct constant,

I need to set required field ErrorMessage like in following code, but it gives me an error.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = string.Format(SystemMessages.Required, "First Name"))]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

`SystemMessages` is a constant file and it has following code,

```
public const string Required = "{0} is required.";
```

Is there any way to set attributes like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string.Format` result is not a compile time constant and can't bee evaluated by the compiler. Attribute values are limited to

> constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type.

More formally, you can find description of limitations at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Formatting a string doesn't fit any of them, which are:

- Simple types (bool, byte, char, short, int, long, float, and double)
- string
- System.Type
- enums
- object (The argument to an attribute parameter of type object must be a constant value of -one of the above types.)
- One-dimensional arrays of any of the above types

At best you can try something similar to:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name" + Required)]
public string FirstName { get; set; }


public const string Required = " is required.";
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`DisplayAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.name.aspx), if you want to output display name instead of property name:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "First Name")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please implement `IValidatableObject` which use `Validate` method. It will look like:

```
  public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
  {
       var memberNames = new List<string>();
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.FirstName )
        {
            memberNames.Add("FirstName");
            yield return new ValidationResult(string.Format(Resources.Required, "First Name"), memberNames);
        }
  }
```

If it is not clear please just read about `IValidatableObject`. Good luck!

Comment: Good solution, but i think there is no way to do remote validations with `IValidatableObject`

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful. What do you mean by 'remote' validation?

Comment: you can put `Remote` a Data Annotation to validate field by ajax request. but in this case seems it is cannot be done